# Pass Remote object in method to RMI server?

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI client that connects to some RMI server just to let it know it can use this new client.

Can I pass directly some Remote object so that:

```
serverRemoteObject.registerClient(theClientRemoteObjectTheServerShouldUse);
```

will actually give the server some object he can use without connecting to my client?
The following question says it is possible, but no real example was given:

[Is it possible to use RMI bidirectional between two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911882/is-it-possible-to-use-rmi-bidirectional-between-two-classes)

Andrew

Comment: The 'without connecting to my client' part is impossible of course, not sure what that's doing there.

Comment: That's indeed incorrect. I meant "without having to ask for an object in a registry on my client".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is how exactly callbacks work in case of RMI. You send across an object to the server and when the server invokes a method on your object, it would be executed in the "client" JVM as opposed to on the server. Look into `UnicastRemoteObject.export` method for export any object which implements the `Remote` interface as a remote object which can be passed to your server.

```
interface UpdateListener extends Remote {

  public void handleUpdate(Object update) throws RemoteException;

}

class UpdateListenerImpl implements UpdateListener {

  public void handleUpdate(Object update) throws RemoteException {
  // do something
  }

}

//somewhere in your client code
final UpdateListener listener = new UpdateListenerImpl();
UnicastRemoteObject.export(listener);
```